# SciPy/Python install on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, python-2.7, scipy

I'm currently following the tutorial *[Installing the SciPy Stack](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux)* to install [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) (I can't use `apt-get install` because I need a recent version).

However, I get errors when I do the following commands:

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local   # Installs to /usr/local

python setup.py build

michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1$ python setup.py buildRunning from scipy source directory.
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1423: UserWarning: 
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries blas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries blas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1432: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1435: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 208, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 199, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 136, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/setup.py", line 8, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('integrate')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 10, in configuration
    blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 320, in get_info
    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 471, in get_info
    raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 18, in <module>
    import problem_report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 14, in <module>
    import zlib, base64, time, sys, gzip, struct, os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 10, in <module>
    import io
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from matlab import loadmat, savemat, byteordercodes
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/matlab/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from mio import loadmat, savemat
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 15, in <module>
    from mio4 import MatFile4Reader, MatFile4Writer
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/matlab/mio4.py", line 9, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from csr import *
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from csr import *
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 25, in <module>
    _csr = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    import _csr
ImportError: No module named _csr

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 208, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 199, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 136, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/setup.py", line 8, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('integrate')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 10, in configuration
    blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 320, in get_info
    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 471, in get_info
    raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
```

sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local   # installs to /usr/local

```
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1$ sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
[sudo] password for michael: 
Running from scipy source directory.
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1423: UserWarning: 
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries blas not found in /usr/lib
  libraries blas not found in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1432: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1435: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 208, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 199, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 136, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/setup.py", line 8, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('integrate')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 10, in configuration
    blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 320, in get_info
    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 471, in get_info
    raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 18, in <module>
    import problem_report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 14, in <module>
    import zlib, base64, time, sys, gzip, struct, os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 10, in <module>
    import io
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from matlab import loadmat, savemat, byteordercodes
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/matlab/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from mio import loadmat, savemat
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 15, in <module>
    from mio4 import MatFile4Reader, MatFile4Writer
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/io/matlab/mio4.py", line 9, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from csr import *
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from csr import *
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 25, in <module>
    _csr = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/michael/Downloads/scipy-0.11.0rc1/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    import _csr
ImportError: No module named _csr

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 208, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 199, in setup_package
    configuration=configuration )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 136, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/setup.py", line 8, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('integrate')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 10, in configuration
    blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 320, in get_info
    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 471, in get_info
    raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
```

Moreover, how do I test if this module was installed correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas/14541175#14541175 also a similar question. It might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/scipy/) is a good way to install it. The version is beta 0.10.1 and it includes all of the dependencies. You need [Active Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) to access PyPM, but that you should be able to install easily.

```
pypm install scipi
```

Comment: PyPM is obsolete

Answer (score 28):

My usual work flow is to use a [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) to have a Python distribution with up-to-date packages.

Within this environment you can than install and update all packages you need with [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) and without any `sudo` calls.

So if you only need [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) (and [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)) this would be:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python-pip
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-numpy python-scipy
$ # Create virtualenv in home
$ virtualenv .myenv
$ # Activate the virtualenv
$ source .myenv/bin/activate
(myenv)$ pip install -U numpy
(myenv)$ pip install -U scipy
```

(If you don't have root access, you can install `virtualenv` and `pip` as described [here](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#installation). However, you need the dependencies of NumPy and SciPy.)

You can include `source .myenv/bin/activate` in your `.bash_profile` and your shell will always start with that environment. If you use [requirement files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) it is easy to install and maintain the same environments on all your machines.

Comment: Thanks much. I was missing the "sudo apt-get build-dep python-numpy python-scipy" step.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem.  The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

Comment: May I ask how did you figured out that those packages solves the problem? Thanks

Comment: Dr Google, from memory.

Comment: these aren't MKL though?

Answer (score 4):

You need to download and install [Atlas](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) as the output suggests. After that, retry the SciPy installation.

Other option would be `apt-get install` older version. This will auto-install all the dependencies; and then install the newer one by hand. This will result in two libraries on your machine, one in `/usr/share/pyshared` most likely and another one somewhere under `/usr/local`, but you can make sure which one is loaded by altering the module loading path.

Also, if you will ommit `--prefix=/usr/local`, while installing newer version on top of older one, it will just get overwritten and the path mangling won't be required.

Comment: You probably need `apt-get build-dep scipy` to install -dev packages that are required to compile it. Just `apt-get install scipy` won't install those.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to build SciPy from source.

If you just want to *install* SciPy, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

Comment: Though this is an answer, I would suggest giving a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the OP (on [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 5.7 for me; yes, I know that's old) and all was fixed by installing the ATLAS headers (and "static libs", it says) via:

```
 yum install atlas-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4, Use following:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas3 liblapack3 liblapack-dev libblas-dev gfortran libatlas-base-dev
```

and then use pip to install latest packages.

```
pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

For [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) 20:

```
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
mkvirtualenv scipy_project
sudo yum-buildep scipy
pip install scipy
```

I hope it helps!