# python : undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, scipy

I get a problem when I try to exec my main file in python (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with python 2.7).
I get this error :

```
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$ python __main__.py Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "__main__.py", line 5, in main
    import launch
  File "/home/michael/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs/launch.py", line 2, in <module>
    import src.lib.utils as fn
  File "/home/michael/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs/src/lib/utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import scipy.signal, numdisplay, sys
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    from bsplines import *
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/bsplines.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scipy.special
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 527, in <module>
    from basic import *
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/basic.py", line 12, in <module>
    import orthogonal
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/orthogonal.py", line 697, in <module>
    from orthogonal_eval import \
ImportError: /home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/orthogonal_eval.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8
```

Currently scipy is installed with [Python Package Manager](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/)  (see my previous post here : [python : scipy install on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863775/python-scipy-install-on-ubuntu).

Thank.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446347/how-to-find-out-if-python-is-compiled-with-ucs-2-or-ucs-4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using a different Python interpreter for running your code than the one used to compile scipy. This usually occurs with a Python installation compiled with Unicode UCS2 support running modules compiled against a Python installation with Unicode UCS4 support (or vis versa). You need to recompile/reinstall the scipy installation with exact the Python interpreter used for running your code.

Comment: Hum, I don't get how I should reinstall scipy.

Comment: @msusplugas If you have `pip` installed, it should be as simple as `pip uninstall scipy && pip install scipy`