# Paraview: paraview.simple import, all paths are set

Tags: python, path, paraview

I am trying to run a simple python program, importing the `paraview.simple` module:

`from paraview.simple import *`

I get the following error:

`Error: Could not import vtkCommonComputationalGeometry`

I looked at similar posts on different fora and tried everything that was suggested there, but nothing worked for me. My Python path includes:

```
ParaView-5.7.0-MPI-Linux-Python2.7-64bit/bin/
ParaView-5.7.0-MPI-Linux-Python2.7-64bit/lib
ParaView-5.7.0-MPI-Linux-Python2.7-64bit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes:

`ParaView-5.7.0-MPI-Linux-Python2.7-64bit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtkmodules/`

Does anybody know how to fix it?

---

Update:
I think there is an underline issue regarding the Unicode variant my python interpreter is using. I now get the following error:
[Unicode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLoH5.jpg)

ImportError: /home/nick/ParaView-5.7.0-MPI-Linux-Python2.7-64bit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtkmodules/vtkCommonCorePython.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8

Does anybody know a fix?

Comment: Looks like an incompatibility between the Python that ParaView was compiled with and the Python you are trying to use. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878666/python-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2-decodeutf8

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `pvpython` program that is bundled with ParaView. It is basically a python interpreter but already setup with the correct paths.

If you want to use an external interpreter, you have to setup the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to `ParaView-5.7.0-MPI-Linux-Python2.7-64bit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (on linux, PATH on windows) to `ParaView-5.7.0-MPI-Linux-Python2.7-64bit/lib`.

See also the ParaViewTutorial pdf from the download page (https://www.paraview.org/download/), at `3.1 Starting the Python Interpreter`