# Pythonpath is still ignored and unable to install locally with pip

Tags: python, numpy, pip, setuptools, distutils

I'm finding that my pythonpath environment variable is ignored. I'm using python 2.6 on ubuntu. I have in my `.bashrc` the following:

`export PTYHONPATH=/my/home/mylibs/lib/python2.6/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH`

Then I install a new version of `numpy` using:

`python setup.py install --prefix=/my/home/mylibs/`

and it gets correctly installed locally. However, when I try to install other packages (also using `setup.py`) that depend on the new version of numpy, they cannot find it, because by default the loaded numpy is the one in `/usr/llib`, and not the one specified in my `PYTHONPATH`. My `PYTHONPATH` gets correctly set but the system-wide directory is still overruling it.

How can this be fixed? I just want my local version of `numpy` to be accessed when I do `import numpy`. I saw other posts related to this with python 2.4 but as far as I can tell it never got resolved. Also, i'd like to do this without installing pip or virtualenv for now. It seems like it should be possible using `--prefix` or `--home` options passed to `setup.py` and then alteration of `PYTHONPATH` but this does not work for me... the system wide `lib` dirs are read first.

*edit*: I try to follow the suggestions and use `pip`. I have a system wide install of an old `pip` that does not recognize `--user` (ver 0.3). I tried to upgrade `pip` with `pip` itself but of course that failed because I cannot install it locally, so `pip install pip --upgrade --user` is not an option. I downloaded a new version of `pip` and installed locally in my home directory but the system wide old one is still used when I type `pip` at the prompt. I looked into the `pip` package and found `runner.py` so I tried to use it to install packages using:

```
runner.py install --user numpy --upgrade
```

That still fails with permission denied:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/f2py2.6'
```

It looks like `--user` is broken. I also am not sure how this would solve the fact that the system wide python uses the system wide packages in `/usr/lib`... is there a solution to this? It seems like it's virtually impossible to install local packages in python nowadays.

Comment: What happens when you run
`PYTHONPATH="/path/to/some/where:$PYTHONPATH" python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)'`

Do you see the new path first?

Comment: Using pip with the `--user` option is the answer to your problem. Why do you not want to install it? Also, do you have an installation of numpy in the system-wide site-packages directory?

Comment: why don't you use `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`?

Comment: @Keith: yes, there's a system wide numpy installation that I cannot control - that's what I am trying to get around. I want my local version to be used instead

Comment: @Keith: I did `pip install numpy` which worked on my system although I don't have root (it does not recognize `--user`). It installed successfully but the system wide version in /usr/ is still read... any ideas?

Comment: @user248237 if you cannot install an up to date system package (12.04 has 1.6.1) or no admin rights, I would install it in a virtual environment. I recently described my work flow here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11864996/1301710

Comment: Apparently nobody spotted this until now: the command given at the start, `export PTYHONPATH=...` has a typo (`PTYHON`, not `PYTHON`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Python will use the first package it finds. The PYTHONPATH gets appended to sys.path, after the system one. So it will normally find the system one first. But the "official" per-user packages directory seems to be placed before that. So create your personal site-packages directory:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
mkdir $HOME/bin
```

(You may have to change "lib64" to "lib32" or just "lib")

This directory gets placed before the system one on my system. But you should verify it by printing out sys.path.

Then install your packages into there. However, the `--user` option in the latest `pip` version should already place it there.

As a list resort you can manipulate `sys.path`. You can insert your directory into sys.path before the system site-packages, then import numpy.

You are getting permissions errors from the scripts installation, trying to put that in the system location. You can pass additional options to install scripts in your $HOME/bin directory.

Install like this:

```
pip install --user --install-option="--install-scripts=$HOME/bin"
```

Comment: I just tried `pip 1.1` with `--user` and it still does not install things locally.  If I do: `pip install --user pandas`, it fails with `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/f2py2.6'`. It still tries to change system wide directories ...

Comment: This directory does not get placed first... the system paths are first

Comment: @user248237 That can't be, since the site.py code explicitly places the user site directory before the system site directory. Unless your site administrator is doing something really odd.