# Can't upgrade Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade `Scipy` from `0.9.0` to `0.12.0`. I use the command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
```

and I get all sorts of errors which can be seen [in the pip.log file here](http://pastebin.com/09JRVDhH) and I'm unfortunately not python-savvy enough to understand what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have yo thought about completely removing scipy 0.9.0 and then building 0.12.0? Also what OS and python version are you using?

Comment: I'd have no problem trying that. I'm running elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu 12.04 and `python` version 2.7.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error messages all state the same: You lack BLAS (Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines) on your system, or scipy cannot find it. When installing packages from source in ubuntu, as you are effectively trying to do with pip, one of the easiest ways to make sure dependencies are in place is by the command

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-scipy
```

which will install all packages needed to build the package `python-scipy`. You may in some cases run into the problem that the version of the source package you are trying to install have different dependencies than the version included with ubuntu, but in your case, I think chances are good that the above command will be sufficient to fetch BLAS for you, headers included.

Comment: Running this command did the trick, I was able to later run `sudo pip install --upgrade scipy` and `scipy` was successfully upgraded. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem upgrading from scipy 0.9 to 0.13.3, and I solved it using the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336915/2548301) and installing:

sudo apt-get install libblas-dev

sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev

sudo apt-get install gfortran

Answer (score 2):

I found [Adam Klein's instructions](http://blog.adamdklein.com/?p=416) for setting up scipy (and friends) in a virtual environment very useful.

One problem I ran into (which was probably my own fault): After all was said and done, I found importing scipy still loaded version 0.9.0, not 0.12.0. The problem was that my `sys.path` was finding the old system version before the new version.
The fix was to make

```
/path/to/.virtualenvs/arthur/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

appear before

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

in `sys.path`. If you have [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) installed, then
you can add the path using

```
add2virtualenv /path/to/.virtualenvs/arthur/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure  libatlas-base-dev and libatlas-sse2-dev are installed, it seems like it can't find your atlas library. Also, see this question:

[Does Python SciPy need BLAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas)