# Upgrade SciPy package through pip producing errors

Tags: python, scipy, pip, anaconda, conda

I tried SciPy upgrade package through pip. It resulted in the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dato Launcher>pip install --upgrade scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.17.0.tar.gz (12.4MB)
    100% |################################| 12.4MB 26kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy
  Complete output from command C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\paushali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-98qqyh\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\tmpj1fbutpip-wheel-:
  lapack_opt_info:
  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_mkl_info:
  mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_lapack95_lp64,mkl_blas95_lp64,mkl_intel_lp64,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,libiomp5md,libifportmd not found in []
    NOT AVAILABLE

    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
  numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
  numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
  numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
  numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:594: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64 is invalid.
    warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
  C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:594: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/compiler/lib/intel64 is invalid.
    warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
  C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:594: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include is invalid.
    warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
  C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1505: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
  C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1516: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
  C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1519: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  Running from scipy source directory.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-98qqyh\scipy\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-98qqyh\scipy\setup.py", line 262, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-98qqyh\scipy\setup.py", line 182, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.15.1
    Uninstalling scipy-0.15.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-0.15.1
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Complete output from command C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\paushali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-98qqyh\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-quoq4v-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_lapack95_lp64,mkl_blas95_lp64,mkl_intel_lp64,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,libiomp5md,libifportmd not found in []
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\libs
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\paushali\\Anaconda\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:594: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64 is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:594: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/compiler/lib/intel64 is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:594: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1505: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1516: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1519: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-98qqyh\scipy\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-98qqyh\scipy\setup.py", line 262, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-98qqyh\scipy\setup.py", line 182, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
Command "C:\Users\paushali\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\paushali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-98qqyh\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-quoq4v-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\paushali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-98qqyh\scipy
```

Please guide how to upgrade package.
Thanks

Comment: Use `conda update scipy` instead. Installing scipy using pip won't work unless you have a working toolchain to compile the C and Fortran extensions, which is not easy to set up on Windows.

Comment: Download the precompiled scipy from here --> http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925381/cant-upgrade-scipy