# Python 2.7 upgrade scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to upgrade my scipy from version 0.13.3 to 0.17 (I need some new functions), I am working in Ubuntu 14.04

I have encountered  the following problems:
the ubuntu repo does not contain the newest version but the one I have already installe. 
Therefore, I have tried to install it using pip

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade scipy
Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-0.17.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy .../
```

But then the intallation procedure remains blocked here. I've looked here on the forum for solutions,
[Can't upgrade Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925381/cant-upgrade-scipy)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/359254/how-to-install-numpy-and-scipy-for-python

But the solutions reported here did not fix my problem.

Comment: I've had similar difficulties in the past, and therefore started using an  anaconda environment in my user's home folder. Alongside (easier) packet management, it provides other useful tools. See https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install

Comment: If you mean the installation is stuck (= you don't get any error message, it just sits there) --- it can just take a long time, 10-20 min is well possible depending on speed of computer