# Issues installing gensim on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, gensim

I am trying to install gensim in Python on my Ubuntu. I tried with  easy_install but getting errors. Could someone help with identifying what is going wrong?

**easy_install**

```
easy_install -U gensim

Running scipy-0.19.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-    QXO1dA/scipy-0.19.1/egg-dist-tmp-AxijnA
/tmp/easy_install-QXO1dA/scipy-0.19.1/setup.py:323: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates 

warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with "                                                                 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning: Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.                                                                     
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the                                                                     numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting                                                                       the ATLAS environment variable.    

self.calc_info()                                                                                                                    
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:                                                 
Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.                                                                          
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the                                                                     
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting                                                                      
the LAPACK environment variable.                                                                                                  
self.calc_info()                                                                                                                  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils
/system_info.py:572: UserWarning:                                                   
Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.                                                                           
Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the                                                                       
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting                                                                  
the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.                                                                                              
self.calc_info()                                                                                                                  
Running from scipy source directory.                                                                                                
non-existing path in 'scipy/integrate': 'quadpack.h'                                                                                
Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting                                                                 
Make sure that Python modules _winreg, win32api or win32con are  installed.                                                          
error: no lapack/blas resources found
```

Thank you

Comment: It's usually best to use virtual environments and the 'pip' installation tool, which avoids mixing packages in your system Python, and automatically handles dependencies. Or, similarly, the `conda` tool, which can also create environments and then `conda install [PACKAGE]` or `pip install [PACKAGE]` into those environments. (I prefer the `miniconda` variant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to upgrade Scipy...followed the solution given in the answer by josteinb in the following thread:

[Can't upgrade Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925381/cant-upgrade-scipy)

Was able to upgrade scipy as follows:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-scipy
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
```

easy_install of gensim worked smoothly after this