# Compiling LAPACK on Solaris

Tags: solaris, lapack, sunos

I'm following the suggestions on [Does Python SciPy need BLAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas) to install scipy locally to my home directory on SunOS (5.10 Generic_147440-12 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440). But although I have Python 2.7 working, numpy installed, and (I think) the BLAS libraries compiled, I can't get LAPACK to play nicely.
My make.inc is make.inc.SUN4SOL2 (is this right?) and I've replaced f77 for f95 for the FORTRAN and LOADER variables, but then I get:

```
We are about to check whether infinity arithmetic
 can be trusted.  If this test hangs, set
 ILAENV = 0 for ISPEC = 10 in LAPACK/SRC/ilaenv.f
*** Error code 136
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `lapack_install'
```

even though I've edited ilaenv.f to set ILAENV = 0 for ISPEC=10 (and ISPEC=11).
Now I'm stuck - if it helps, my compiler identifies itself as:

```
file `which f95`
/usr/local/rlib/SunStudio11/SUNWspro/bin/f95:   ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, dynamically linked, stripped
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris

OK - some progress: I've added the -ftrap=%none flag to my make.inc, and installed GNU make to use instead of whatever solaris provides me with and we're over the last error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seem to have scipy and LAPACK / BLAS installed on the system now. So in case it helps anyone, the secret seems to be to add -ftrap=%none to the flags in make.inc copied from INSTALL/make.inc.SUN4SOL and (on building scipy) to set the environment variables LAPACK and BLAS to point to the appropriate libraries once compiled.