# How to install Scipy on ec2 server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, scipy, remote-access

I'm getting stuck on installing scipy on ec2. So I was trying to get the file to download, and it shows the following errors. What am I missing? Thanks so much! Really newbie here to working with remote environments.

```
$ curl http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/scipy/scipy/0.11.0/scipy-0.11.0.zip?r=&amp;ts=1364951046&amp;use_mirror=iweb
[1] 2355
-bash: amp: command not found
[2] 2357
-bash: amp: command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

You can installed it via [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)

1. sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
2. sudo pip install numpy #scipy depends on numpy
3. sudo pip install scipy

P.S. I recommend you install step 2 and 3 on virtualenv

### EDIT

Seems you should install `Fortune` before step 3. You can take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas)

### EDIT

Finally, I launch a new EC2 instance and installed it for you:

1. sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
2. sudo pip install numpy
3. sudo apt-get install gfortran
4. sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
5. sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
6. sudo apt-get install g++
7. sudo pip install scipy

Hope these might work.

Comment: Hi @waitingkuo, thank you for the answer. I tried the steps in the link you mention in the Edit part, and ran into this problem where g77 / ifort / gfortran all show: Command not found. Is there other ways to compile the Fortran file?

Comment: Have added the steps to install gfortran and its modules.

Comment: Thank you so much @waitingkuo -So I tried sudo apt-get install gfortran, and it returned command not found. So I tried sudo yum install gfortran and it returned 'No package gfortran possible'. Error: Nothing to do'

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Try `sudo yum install gcc-gfortran` instead.

Comment: Thanks! So i successfully installed gcc-gfortran. Now I tried sudo pip install scipy, it show here "Command /home/ec2-user/env/dir/bin/python2.6 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/ec2-user/env/dir/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-WqmkNL-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/ec2-user/env/dir/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1 in /home/ec2-user/env/dir/build/scipy"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27463/discussion-between-msunbot-and-waitingkuo)

Comment: On my EC2 instance I had to run:
sudo apt-get install python-dev