# What is the easiest way to install BLAS and LAPACK for scipy?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to run a programme that someone else has prepared and it includes scipy. I have tried to install scipy with

```
pip install scipy
```

but it gives me a long error. I know there are ways with Anaconda and Canopy but I think these are long ways. I would like to have a short way. I have also tried

```
G:\determinator_Oskar>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy
  Complete output from command g:\myve\scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;
__file__='e:\\temp_n~1\\pip-build-1xigxu\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__f
ile__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d e:\temp_
n~1\tmp07__zrpip-wheel-:
  lapack_opt_info:
  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['g:\\myve\\lib', 'C:\\']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_mkl_info:
  mkl_info:
    libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['g:\\myve\\lib', 'C:\\']
    NOT AVAILABLE

    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['g:\\myve\\lib', 'C:\\']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

    NOT AVAILABLE

  g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
  g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
  g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  Running from scipy source directory.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "e:\temp_n~1\pip-build-1xigxu\scipy\setup.py", line 253, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "e:\temp_n~1\pip-build-1xigxu\scipy\setup.py", line 250, in setup_packa
ge
      setup(**metadata)
    File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup

      config = configuration()
    File "e:\temp_n~1\pip-build-1xigxu\scipy\setup.py", line 175, in configurati
on
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in
 add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in
get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in
_get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in
 add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in
get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in
_get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Complete output from command g:\myve\scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptool
s, tokenize;__file__='e:\\temp_n~1\\pip-build-1xigxu\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(comp
ile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __fi
le__, 'exec'))" install --record e:\temp_n~1\pip-3hncqr-record\install-record.tx
t --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers g:\myve\includ
e\site\python2.7\scipy:
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['g:\\myve\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['g:\\myve\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in g:\myve\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['g:\\myve\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "e:\temp_n~1\pip-build-1xigxu\scipy\setup.py", line 253, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "e:\temp_n~1\pip-build-1xigxu\scipy\setup.py", line 250, in setup_pac
kage
        setup(**metadata)
      File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in set
up
        config = configuration()
      File "e:\temp_n~1\pip-build-1xigxu\scipy\setup.py", line 175, in configura
tion
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001,
in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, i
n get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, i
n _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001,
in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, i
n get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "g:\myve\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, i
n _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "g:\myve\scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='e:
\\temp_n~1\\pip-build-1xigxu\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'o
pen', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record e:\temp_n~1\pip-3hncqr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-exter
nally-managed --compile --install-headers g:\myve\include\site\python2.7\scipy"
failed with error code 1 in e:\temp_n~1\pip-build-1xigxu\scipy
```

I have also tried

```
pip install lapack
```

with this result

```
Collecting lapack
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lapack (from versions
 )
No matching distribution found for lapack
```

I have also tried

```
pip install blas
```

with similar results

```
G:\determinator_Oskar>pip install blas
Collecting blas
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blas (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for blas
```

Why does a scipy get so complicated ?

Comment: I did `yum install lapack` which installed lapack and blas, but it didn't solve the problem either...

Comment: `sudo yum install blas-devel lapack-devel` needed on RedHat or CentOS. `sudo apt-get install gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev python-dev` on Debian or Ubuntu. YMMV.

Comment: @gaoithe If I use that redhat command on a fresh EC2 Redhat image, I get an error message because that packages are not available. (i.e. wrong package name)

Comment: @falsePockets try libblas-devel and liblapack-devel and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777836/how-to-install-scipy-on-ec2-server

Comment: I was facing the same problem, upgrading pip helped me

Comment: 'I know there are ways with Anaconda and Canopy but I think these are long ways.' Did you know conda was literally invented for this exact problem? Thinking is great; but have you tried, you know, trying?

Comment: I was facing the same issue and I fixed it by doing `export OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)"`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [SciPy installation page](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) already recommends several ways of installing python with SciPy already included, such as [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/).

Another way is to use [wheels](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels) (a built-package format):

```
pip install SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

The wheel packages you can find on: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

For SciPy you need:

- the [NumPy wheel packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
- and the [SciPy wheel packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

Comment: Hey guys, thank you and thank God for miniconda. It worked like a miracle. Install and run `conda install scipy`, like you suggested @jakedvp. Now my programme is running and I am happy. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I have windows 10 and it doesn't allow me to install using wheels. What can I do

Comment: Have you tried any of the other solutions? If that still doesn't work, you can ask a new question, explaining what you have tried and what errors you got.

Comment: This worked for me. I downloaded the *.whl file and copied to the directory where pip is installed and then ran the command as "pip install filename.whl"

Comment: it's `numpy` that warns about BLAS and LAPACK. Using `numpy` wheel does not solve the problem, since it does not contains the optimized libraries. Furthermore, `scipy` already requires `numpy`, so...

Comment: On the page, there is no information whatsoever about blas/lapack instalation, and the wheel do not cover all versions you could need.

Answer (score 61):

For **Debian Jessie** and **Stretch** installing the following packages resolves the issue:

```
sudo apt install libblas3 liblapack3 liblapack-dev libblas-dev
```

---

Your **next** issue is very likely going to be a missing Fortran compiler, resolve this by installing it like this:

```
sudo apt install gfortran
```

---

If you want an optimized scipy, you can also install the optional `libatlas-base-dev` package:

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
```

[Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/linux.html#debian-ubuntu)

---

If you have any issue with a missing Python.h file like this:

> Python.h: No such file or directory

Then have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/209532

Comment: I had to follow these steps on `minimized Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`

Comment: This way you get an unoptimized BLAS library. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515996/1763602) (the source is `scipy` docs themselves)

Answer (score 30):

> "Why does a scipy get so complicated?

It gets so complicated because Python's package management system is built to track Python package dependencies, and SciPy and other scientific tools have dependencies beyond Python. [Wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) fix part of the problem, but my experience is that tools like `pip`/`virtualenv` are just not sufficient for installing and managing a scientific Python stack.

If you want an easy way to get up and running with SciPy, I would highly suggest the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It will give you everything you need for scientific computing in Python.

If you want a "short way" of doing this (I'm interpreting that as "I don't want to install a huge distribution"), you might try [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) and then run `conda install scipy`.

Answer (score 6):

Always for Ubuntu/Debian, [chjortlund's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50234992/1763602) it's very good but not perfect, since this way you get an unoptimized BLAS library. You have simply to do:

```sh
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
```

and voila'!

[Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/linux.html#debian-ubuntu)

Comment: You may need to install the fortran compiler as well: `apt install gfortran`

Comment: @jstm This is already explained in chjortlund's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using conda install scipy instead of pip solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

For windows: Best is to use pre-compiled package available from this site: 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, though this probably would not work well given your particular setup (external program + Windows), one can also acquire Scipy hassle-free as part of the (large) [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org) download.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [SciPy whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), download the appropriate one and run `pip install <whl_file>`

OR

Read through [SciPy Windows issue and run one of the methods](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html).

OR

Use [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html).

Additionally, install [Visual C++ compiler for python2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) in-case it asks for it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem on freeBSD.
It seems lapack packages are missing, I solved it installing them (as root) with:

```
pkg install lapack
pkg install atlas-devel  #not sure this is needed, but just in case
```

I imagine it could work on other system too using the appropriate package installer (e.g. apt-get)

Answer (score 0):

`pip install Cython`

before

`pip install sklearn`

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install liblapack
```

this worked for me