# Python Neupy install : no lapack/blas resources found

Tags: python, windows, python-packaging, neupy

I cannot install the package Neupy. I work with Python 3.5 and Windows 10..

I tried to clone it from the source code as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/itdxer/neupy.git
cd neupy
python setup.py install
```

Here the error I got:

```
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
error: no lapack/blas resources found
```

Also, I followed the solution given in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33369271/7492898

```
pip install neupy-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I got another problem here:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 310, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 748, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 798, in unpack_url
unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 705, in unpack_file_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
File "c:\users\python\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 482, in unzip_file
zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\neupy\\neupy-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
```

**EDIT :**   The solution was to use the whl from the official source which checks for the dependencies of lapack/blas:

1. Download the version of scipy suited for your OS and version lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
2. Then enter the command:

   ```
   pip install [Local File Location]\[Your specific file such as scipy-0.16.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl]
   ```
3. Finally pip works well for neupy:

   ```
    pip install neupy
   ```

Comment: Unless you downloaded the whl file, doing that wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget everything you done before, all you need to do is type this in the Windows cmd to install neupy from Pypi.

```
pip install neupy
```

If you need more information see here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/neupy

Comment: It was my initial cmd but the error remains numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

Comment: Have you installed numpy and scipy?

Comment: Yes both are installed

Comment: Download the version suited for your OS and version http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: It works after installing scipy via .whl... Why the install via pip was different? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the whl from the official source checks to install lapack/blas if your computer doesn't have them. While the Pypi doesn't