# How to install time_complexity_analyzer package?

Tags: python, pip, time-complexity

I have found a package in GitHub which can clearly tell the time complexity of a python code, The link for the package that I have found in GitHub is [here](https://github.com/MieszkoMakuch/time-complexity-estimator).
I tried installing it in my PC using "**pip install time_complexity_estimator**" but I ended up with some errors.

Someone please tell me how to install it.

The reply from my command prompt is follows :

```
Collecting time_complexity_estimator
  Using cached time_complexity_estimator-0.3.tar.gz (12 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting numpy==1.11.3
  Using cached numpy-1.11.3.zip (4.7 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting scipy==0.18.1
  Using cached scipy-0.18.1.zip (14.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: scipy, numpy, time_complexity_estimator
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.8.0
    Uninstalling scipy-1.8.0:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.8.0
  DEPRECATION: scipy is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for scipy did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [142 lines of output]
      C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xchf9ate\scipy_18ce00d69bde46538e9e7da6667a7b99\setup.py:115: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
        import imp

      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


      INFO: lapack_opt_info:
      INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
      INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler
      INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
      INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      INFO: get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      INFO: customize GnuFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable g77
      WARN: Could not locate executable f77
      INFO: customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifl
      INFO: customize AbsoftFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable f90
      INFO: customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable DF
      INFO: customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable efl
      INFO: customize Gnu95FCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable f95
      INFO: customize G95FCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable g95
      INFO: customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      INFO: customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable efort
      WARN: Could not locate executable efc
      INFO: customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      WARN: Could not locate executable flang
      WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: flame_info:
      INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: accelerate_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_info:
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\sanja\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO: lapack_src_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      Running from scipy source directory.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xchf9ate\scipy_18ce00d69bde46538e9e7da6667a7b99\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xchf9ate\scipy_18ce00d69bde46538e9e7da6667a7b99\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
          config = configuration()
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xchf9ate\scipy_18ce00d69bde46538e9e7da6667a7b99\setup.py", line 335, in configuration
          config.add_subpackage('scipy')
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1054, in add_subpackage
          config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1020, in get_subpackage
          config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 962, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
          config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xchf9ate\scipy_18ce00d69bde46538e9e7da6667a7b99\scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
          config.add_subpackage('linalg')
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1054, in add_subpackage
          config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1020, in get_subpackage
          config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 962, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
          config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
        File "C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xchf9ate\scipy_18ce00d69bde46538e9e7da6667a7b99\scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
          raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
      numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
  Moving to c:\users\sanja\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\scipy-1.8.0.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\~cipy-1.8.0.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\sanja\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\
   from C:\Users\sanja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\~cipy
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> scipy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Those versions of numpy and scipy are *really* old, and your system failed to compile them for the reasons shown. That means the module you're trying to install hasn't been maintained in years, and may not work even if its requirements were updated.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/a/33369271/5446749 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found

Comment: I get it sir, Is there any possibilities to get it now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

I *think* this is a bug on the developer's end, not yours. I tried running it and I got the same result. I also tried cloning the repository manually and using the setup.py file, but that also threw me an error.

I've posted an issue on the repository to alert the developer's that this is happening. I recommend you do the same, since it might grab more attention. Otherwise, I'm not sure what to suggest. I apologize if this isn't the answer you're looking for!

Edit: this is what I got, and based on our similar experiences, I think that it is an issue on our end. It could not be, it might just be a coincidence, so I'd also ask a friend to see if they can install the module.

Comment: Okay sir thank you for you response I think I got the answer from you Thank you sir :)