# Python scipy needs BLAS

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, setup.py

I have `scipy` as a dependency in my python program which I am trying to package using `setuptools`.

I used `install_requires=['scipy','matplotlib']` in my setup.py.

On running `python setup.py install`

```
Processing dependencies for Bland==1.0.a.dev1
Searching for scipy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Best match: scipy 0.13.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.3.zip#md5=20ff3a867cc5925ef1d654aed2ff7e88
Processing scipy-0.13.3.zip
```

it goes on until it show 3 to 4 warnings and an error as follows

```
ages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1522: UserWarning: 
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/home/storm/Documents/bland/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1531: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
/home/storm/Documents/bland/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1534: UserWarning: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
error: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas), but this is installing scipy without `setup.py` which tells to download, and then compile the fortran files, and finally link them to one lib which must then be on your search path when installing scipy. But how am I supposed to do this from `setup.py` or is there a work around.

**FYI**: I am running this in `virtualenv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you cannot use the `setup.py` to install system libraries. This mechanism is only thought for Python packages and their C extensions (which may define their own dependencies on C shared libraries, but this is not a solution here).

There are a number of solutions you may try but they are all outside the `setup.py` file:

- create an installer (RPM, DEB or Windows package) where you define your dependency on the Atlas package. The system package manager (yum, apt-get, hmmm... nothing on Windows) is then in charge of finding the lib and installing it for your package.

  - RPM: [remember](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html) you get a `bdist_rpm` command from the `setup.py` directly
  - Windows: [remember](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html) you also get a `bdist_msi` command from the `setup.py`
  - DEB: the [stdeb package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) create a `bdist_deb` command
- use [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/docs/index.html) as build mechanism

  - define Atlas as a `part`
  - use the `cmmi` recipe in order to download, configure, make and "make install" the Atlas tarball
  - set the `os.environ` ATLAS variable to the `parts` directory of your buildout inside your `setup.py` before you define your package's `setup`.
- simply list Atlas as a dependency of your package and let your users install it. Keep the `scipy` dependency within your `setup.py`; that is the correct place, since it is a Python package.