# How to install scipy in python 2.6

Tags: python, scipy

I want to install scipy in python 2.6 in linux. But when I am installing scipy 0.14.1 it throws error.How can I resolve it.The traceback is as follows.

```
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/local/lib64
libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/local/lib
libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib64
libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in /usr/lib
NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
NOT AVAILABLE


File "setup.py", line 196, in <module>
setup_package()
File "setup.py", line 187, in setup_package
configuration=configuration )
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
config = configuration()
File "setup.py", line 138, in configuration
config.add_subpackage('scipy')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py  1002,     in    
caller_level = 2)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in    get_subpackage
caller_level = caller_level + 1)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
File "scipy/setup.py", line 8, in configuration
config.add_subpackage('integrate')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1002, in add_subpackage
caller_level = 2)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 971, in ge  t_subpackage
caller_level = caller_level + 1)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 908, in _g  et_configuration_from_setup_py
config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 10, in configuration
blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 311, in get_info
return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 462, in get_info
raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
the BLAS environment variable.
```

Comment: Have you installed the development versions of (lib)blas and (lib)atlas on your system?

Comment: What Linux distribution do you use?

Comment: Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas and the various answers (both the manual install and ones using package mangers).

Comment: I will install the blas and atlas.then lets see.. ok thans

Comment: Linux is :Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)

Answer (score -1):

You can use virtualenv as a tool to use any version of python including 2.6 or 2.7 or 3.4

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem.