# SciPy package on Fedora 20: ImportError: cannot import name anderson_ksamp

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fedora, bioinformatics

I'm trying to run a Python package called D3E for single-cell differential gene expression. I have Python 2.7.5 on Fedora 20. I just installed the SciPy package using the [instructions here](http://www.scipy.org/install.html):

```
sudo yum install numpy scipy python-matplotlib ipython python-pandas sympy python-nose
```

However, when I try to run the script, I keep getting a SciPy error:

```
bash-4.2$ python D3ECmd.py ~/Documents/geneExpressionTable.txt ~/outputFile.txt cellType1 cellTYpe2 -n=0, -z=1

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D3ECmd.py", line 34, in <module>
        from D3EUtil import readData, getParamsBayesian, getParamsMoments, cramerVonMises, logStatus, goodnessOfFit, distributionTest
      File "/home/user/Software/D3E/D3EUtil.py", line 36, in <module>
        from scipy.stats import gmean, ks_2samp, anderson_ksamp
    ImportError: cannot import name anderson_ksamp
```

What would you recommend I try to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes the repositories have outdated modules. From the command prompt, type "python." Then "import scipy" and "scipy.__version__" - what do you get?

Comment: As @MattY suggests, check the scipy version.  `anderson_ksamp` was added in scipy version 0.14.0.

Comment: Looks like Fedora 20 has scipy 0.12.1 (https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/scipy).

Comment: Thanks, guys. It looks like I have version 0.12.1 indeed. So I suppose I have to install the most current scipy version. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks again for your help :) It's all sorted out now.

Comment: Lol, I just noticed that you've got it running now. Have fun. :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Warren pointed out, anderson_ksamp is not available in scipy version .12.1. It is a relatively new addition to scipy.

I'm **not** a fedora user. That said, it sounds like installing scipy using pip is your best bet.

**Step one:** install dependencies. Check Muneeb's answer for information on how to [install blas and lapack on fedora.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/does-python-scipy-need-blas) It should be as simple as:

> sudo yum install lapack lapack-devel blas blas-devel

**Step two:** install scipy using pip.

> sudo pip install --upgrade scipy

This process will take a long time. Get lunch. You should have a working copy of scipy when you get back.

*Note, if you don't have pip, run the following command:*

> sudo yum install python-pip