# lapack/blas-related error when trying to add scipy to miniconda-installed copy of python 2.7.10 on RedHat 6

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, redhat, lapack, blas

I have two versions of `python` on my RedHat 6 machine: `2.7.8` that came with the system originally and `2.7.10` that I've installed using `miniconda` for a project. I have to use the newer version to run some demo code for another project. The demo script produced this error:

```
ImportError: No module named scipy.sparse
```

Running `pip install scipy` failed with a bunch of warnings and then this:

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

`numpy` is already installed. That is, I get `Requirement already satisfied` when trying to `pip install numpy`.

The `yum install` command recommended on the [SciPy install page](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) completed fine but did not help, probably because this python version is installed at a non-default location.

Same result after building `blas` and `lapack` from source as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/does-python-scipy-need-blas)

How do I get `scipy` to install properly?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Anaconda/miniconda, then use the conda package manager, not pip: 
`conda install scipy`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have lapack/blas library.

try this.

```
yum install python-devel python-nose python-setuptools gcc gcc-gfortran gcc-c++ blas-devel lapack-devel atlas-devel
```

it will install all what you need.

Answer (score 0):

### Value of a *Peace of mind* once starting always from a [Defined state]

There are many issues with `pip` / `yum` installer strategies that we, mortals, can spend ages on our attempts to get resolved.

Since I started to use the Travis Oliphant's **`Anaconda` *fully-fledged* package-manager**, these dependency-related / version-colliding issues simply disappeared. Well did not disappear, but principally do not appear.

### Why?

`Anaconda` package-manager both allows one to keep separate versions ready / reconfigurable via `Anaconda` for individual python launches

and

`Anaconda` resolves updates in a smart way, one would never experience with manual/semi-manual `pip`/`yum` installers

In other words, if you strive to get rid of issues, opt to install Anaconda and start using it's (parallel) multi-versions installation / setup controls and it's smart package-manager facilities.

n.b.: this is not a commercial/spam/PR, this is just personal experience after many years of troubles with individual package updates' collisions / compatibility back-testing troubles in multi-py 2.5 / 2.6 / 2.7 installations environments