# Cannot solve no lapack/blas when installing scipy in virtualenv( while numpy, scikit-learn are ok)

Tags: linux, scipy, virtualenv, lapack, blas

I work on linux(Redhat), python27 virtualenv. I can install numpy by ENV/PATH/bin/pip install numpy, but get error msg(no lapack/blas) below when installing scipy in the same way. Besides, building scipy from src file can not work, as expected. I have tried the way described in [Does Python SciPy need BLAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/does-python-scipy-need-blas)  step by step, but still does not work. Could some one tell me any way I can try? Thanks very much

```
  /home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 253, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 250, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 175, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "/home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/home/szh702/virtenv/install_file/numpy-1.10.1/habitslab/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

Comment: Just like it says, you need to install BLAS and LAPACK. You seem to be on some flavor of linux, your distro's package manager most likely has one.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/does-python-scipy-need-blas, which has a right `yum` incantation at least for Fedora.