# SciPy and ggplot install for python3.4

Tags: python, linux, ggplot2, scipy, pip

I was trying to install ggplot using `pip install ggplot`. As it turned out, I was missing many essential packages, like stated in  [SciPy and blas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/does-python-scipy-need-blas/14541175#14541175) and in [SciPy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip/3625365#3625365). After running 
`sudo apt-get install build-essential gfortran libatlas-base-dev python-pip python-dev` I didn't get these "Cannot build wheel" errors anymore, luckily.

Now as I am trying just `pip install scipy` (which I need apparently) it fetches the package informations and gets stuck at `Running setup.py install for scipy ... /`. I can't imagine it takes this long time to install a 12 MB package (I waited for 30 minutes). Pip won't list it, so it's not isntalled. Does it really take so long? Or do I have another problem here, now? What am I missing?

I am running python3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT:
When trying `pip install ggplot` it gets stuck at the setup.py install for scipy too...

EDIT2:
It seems installing the package scipy for python3 did the trick. It is just completely unclear, why I need so many different packages from different sources to just get it to run. Anyhoo, scipy works and ggplot as well.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question, just want to make sure you know about [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) because it greatly simplifies this sort of thing.

Comment: I know about Anaconda, but this just wasn't an option for this question. I use it for windows, because of its benefits, though.

Comment: sudo pip3 install ggplot (I'm on Ubuntu 15.04)

Answer (score 2):

Scipy is compiling a lot of stuff. Depending on your computer it might take some time.

try:

```
pip -v install scipy
pip -vv install scipy
pip -vvv install scipy
```

(more and more verbose logging output)

Comment: Not exactly solving my problem, but the -v flag is pretty awesome. Didn't knew about that. Thanks!